# Twig doesn't recognize variable passed into template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to render several things on the page at once (latest articles, newest events, ...). I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine2.

This is what my controller code looks like:

```
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Article')->findOrderedByDate(3);
    $events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Event')->findOrderedByDate(2);


    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($events);

    return $this->render('MyAppBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
      'articles' => $articles,
      'events', $events
    ));
  }
```

The dump of the events reveals that it's a StdArray with one item in it (the event from my database). However, if I try to visit the page I get the following Symfony2 error:

```
Variable "events" does not exist in MyAppBundle:Page:index.html.twig at line 47
```

The relevant Twig template part is as follows (it's the exact same as the articles):

```
{% for event in events %}
  <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
  <p class="small">{{ event.eventdate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</p>
  <p>{{ event.intro }} <a href="#">Lees meer &raquo;</a></p>
  <hr class="dotted">
{% endfor %}
```

It seems to me that variables aren't being passed into the view properly, since I can't even display a hardcoded string (i.e. 'fruit', 'banana').

Has anyone got a clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'events', $events` should be changed to `'events' => $events`

Comment: Well, now I just feel really dumb. That fixed it. Thanks!